# 1970s-era short story about an insecure woman treated by a computerized therapist, computer become neurotic?

Tags: story-identification

I'm almost 100% positive this one comes from the mid-late 1970s.

The story starts off in a crowded elevator, with the protagonist (a young woman, probably in her early 20's) fretting about various things.  She's chiding herself for having garlic bread with her lunch, as she's feeling a bit bloated and is sure the other passengers can smell her garlic breath.  She is mortified when she looks down and notices her ugly big toe has pushed through a tear in her pantyhose.  That sort of thing.

She gets off at the floor where the therapist she is going to meet is.  As mentioned before, the therapist is actually a computer programmed to counsel people.  A series of Q&A's between the woman and the computer ensue.  IIRC, the course of the conversation becomes somewhat comical, and the computer-therapist becomes a bit perplexed at some of the responses.

The woman leaves the session feeling great about herself.  The things that bothered her previously she now sees in a positive light.  Her exposed toe is akin to a blossom pushing up from the earth and showing itself (or something like that).  In the elevator down, a handsome man next to her notes she had Italian food for lunch (due to the garlic breath). She flashes him a smile, says "you should try my lasagna", and suggests a dinner date.

Meanwhile, in the final paragraph, the computer-therapist is going through a litany of humorous self-queries, all of them indicative of newly-found insecurities.  The healer has become the patient, so to speak.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story is Transference, by the late [Sharon Webb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharon_Webb).  The story appeared in the July, 1980 issue of [Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/7/79/ASFJUL80.jpg). I found my copy of the issue in my attic.  I have been unable to find the story online.

The protagonist's name is Marilyn Taylor, a nervous 30-something with a therapy appointment with a computerized therapist designed by Allied Meditronics.  The details are pretty much as I remembered them.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/Asimovs_v04n07_1980-07#page/n91/mode/2up